# Change the height of navigation bar in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

I am still new to Swift, but have almost finished my first app. Just two things are bothering me.

1.) I want the distance between the back button be higher and distance to the "active session"-text to be smaller

[image]

2.) I want the text "Bike" and "Controller" to be higher while the rest should stay where it is.

[image]

How can I change/adjust that the easiest way?

Comment: FYI. I do not have a Viewcontroller in place but work with structs

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but generally I'd discourage you from modifying the navigation bar. Depending on what you want to do it might turn out easy as you start, but you will end up fighting a battle on every screen, every iOS update, issues between notch and notchless devices and so on. So take my advice: don't mess with standard components, it will save you many hours and headaches ;)

Also if you want helpful answers we need more information. Did you use UIKit or SwiftUI for your app?

Comment: ... and add some, please.

Comment: I used SwiftUI and what do you want me to add?

Comment: I don't think you need here NavigationView, at least with bar, at all - get rid of it and just transition between views.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but how can I transition between two views? I commented the "next" navigationview button and now I can't get to the active session page

Comment: the view code looks like this: 

var body: some View { 
NavigationView { 
ZStack { 
Color("Themecolor") 
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) 
VStack { 
HStack(spacing: 0) { 
Text("BIKE") 
.font(.system(size: 52)) 
.fontWeight(.bold) 
.foregroundColor(.white) 
Text("Controller") 
.font(.system(size: 52)) 
.foregroundColor(.black) 
.background( 
.white) 
} 
.offset(y: -50)

and suddenly, the white color background of the "Controller"-text extends to the top of the screen

Comment: I tried using .frame on the vstack, but nothing changes